# SQL%ROWCOUNT returns 1 though no rows were updated

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is a part of my plsql block. Even when the rows are updated it returns only 1. what am i missing here.

```
IF p_run_mode='U' THEN    
                BEGIN    
                   update tbbdetc set tbbdetc_desc = lv_new_detail_desc
                           where tbbdetc_detail_code = lv_detail_cd
                             and tbbdetc_dcat_code = lv_dcat_cd;
                   lv_upd_count := SQL%ROWCOUNT;               

                EXCEPTION 
                   WHEN OTHERS THEN
                        utl_file.put_line(lv_out_file,'Update Error: '||SQLERRM||','||lv_detail_cd||'\n',autoflush=>TRUE);               
                END; 

             END IF;
         END LOOP;
           gb_common.p_commit();
           utl_file.put_line(lv_out_file, 'Total Count: '||lv_total_count, Autoflush=>True);
           utl_file.put_line(lv_out_file, 'Updated rows: '||lv_upd_count, Autoflush=>True);
           utl_file.fclose(lv_out_file);
```

Comment: are you sure that `gb_common.p_commit();` contains `commit` ? What message returns when you issue the code?

Comment: `Even when the rows are updated it returns only 1` -->  This is coz you have put  `lv_upd_count := SQL%ROWCOUNT; ` in loop. So everytime the loop runs, it re-assigns the no. of rows updated to `lv_upd_count` and in your case its `1`. So at the end of the last row, it just prints the rows updated at last.

Comment: Yes, @XING nailed it precisely. Not easy given your partial code example. Consider using FORALL-UPDATE, then SQL%ROWCOUNT will give you total. Otherwise: lv_upd_count := lv_upd_count  + SQL%ROWCOUNT;

Comment: @stevenFeuerstein thank you . I tried lv_upd_count := lv_upd_count + SQL%ROWCOUNT , it returns all the rows even if the rows are not updated.

Comment: @-XING thank you for explaining

Comment: @Barbaros yes it does have commit

Comment: @arsha I am not sure what you mean by "it returns all the rows even if the rows are not updated."